# Store XTS objects as data frames in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, xts

I wish to store some XTS objects as data frames within a list in R.

The XTS objects are stock price data collected using the tidyquant package, I need to convert these objects to data frames and store them in a list. I have one additional requirement, I only want to retain the index column and the closing price column for each stock.

I have tried using dplyr syntax to select the columns of interest but my code fails to select column indexes greater than 2

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 3 and 4 don't exist.
i There are only 2 columns.
```

This is the code I am using but I am struggling to understand how I can't select the closing price from my 'fortified' data frames

```
pacman::p_load(tidyquant,tidyverse,prophet)

tickers = c("AAPL","AMZN")

getSymbols(tickers, 
           from = '2015-01-01',
           to = today(),
           warnings = FALSE,
           auto.assign = TRUE)

dfList <- list()

for (i in tickers) {
  dfList[[i]] <- fortify.zoo(i) %>% 
    select(c(1,5))
  }
```

When I convert an individual XTS object to a data frame using fortify.zoo I can select the columns of interest but not when I loop through them.

```
fortify.zoo(AAPL) %>% select(c(1,5)) %>% head(n = 10)
```

Can anyone help me understand where I am falling down in my understanding on this issue please?

Comment: I recommend you use [Gabor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65470859/271616) that takes advantage of `getSymbols()`'s `env` argument and uses `eapply()` or `lapply()` to create a list by iterating over the environment, extracting the (adjusted) close, and fortifying it into a data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to initialize a `list` with fixed length and `name` it with the `tickers`.  In the OP's code, it is looping over the `tickers` directly, so each 'i' is the ticker name which is a string

```
dfList <- vector('list', length(tickers))
names(dfList) <- tickers
```

As the `i` here is a string name of the object `"AAPL"` or `"AMZN"`, we can use `get` to return the value of that object from the global env

```
for (i in tickers) {
  dfList[[i]] <- fortify.zoo(get(i)) %>% 
             select(c(1,5))
   }
```

-check the dimensions

```
sapply(dfList, dim)
#    AAPL AMZN
#[1,] 1507 1507
#[2,]    2    2
```

---

Another approach is `mget` to return all those objects into a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
dfList2 <-  mget(tickers) %>%
     map(~ fortify.zoo(.x) %>% 
             select(1, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

`getSymbols` can put the stock data into an environment `stocks` and `Cl` will extract the close and the Index.  Replace `Cl` with `Ad` if you want the adjusted close. Then iterate through the names  in the environment. Finally leave it as an environment `stocks` or optionally convert it to a list `L`. No packages other than quantmod and the packages that it pulls in are used.  Also there is the question if you even need to convert the data to data frames. You could just leave it as xts.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers = c("AAPL","AMZN")

stocks <- new.env()
getSymbols(tickers, env = stocks, from = '2015-01-01')

for(nm in ls(stocks)) stocks[[nm]] <- fortify.zoo(Cl(stocks[[nm]]))

L <- as.list(stocks) # optional
```

Another possibility if you do want a list is to replace the last two lines with an `eapply`:

```
L <- eapply(stocks, function(x) fortify.zoo(Cl(x)))
```