# Getting historical prices from vector with tickers in R

Tags: r, vector, time-series, stock, portfolio

I am trying to create a model using financial ratios and other characteristics. I have gotten to the point where I am trying to use the tickers in a vector to download historical data. However I cannot seem to find a code automatically download the historical data from all the tickers in this vector, instead of manually putting in every single ticker. I want to create a script where I can change the ratios in order to get a new strategy I can backtest using historical data.

This is what I have done so far:

```
library(readr)
Stocks_in_the_SP_500_Index <- read_csv("Downloads/Stocks in the SP 500 Index.csv")
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
library(xts)

New_list<- getQuote(Stocks_in_the_SP_500_Index$Symbol, what = yahooQF(c("Market Capitalization", "Earnings/Share", 
                                "P/E Ratio", "Book Value", "EBITDA", "52-week Range", "Dividend Yield")))


Strategy<- na.omit(New_list[New_list$`Earnings/Share` >= 3 & New_list$`P/E Ratio` <= 15 
                            & New_list$`Book Value` > 1 & New_list$`Dividend Yield`> 0.037, ])

Stocks<- rownames(Strategy)
Stocks<- as.data.frame(t(Stocks))

prices <- getSymbols(Stocks, src = 'yahoo', from = "2012-06-01") #Is this maybe note the most efficent code to extract the data?
```

Comment: Please run `dput` on `Stocks_in_the_SP_500_Index` and paste the output into your question as a reproducible dataset, otherwise it is difficult for others to assist.

Comment: use package `yfR` to download all the sp500 tickers in one go.

Comment: `getSymbols` can accept a vector of ticker symbols.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65470622/store-xts-objects-as-data-frames-in-a-list-in-r/65470859#65470859